# Capturing a time in milliseconds

Tags: c++, stl, timer, resolution

The following piece of code is used to print the time in the logs:

```
#define PRINTTIME() struct tm  * tmptime;
time_t     tmpGetTime;
time(&tmpGetTime);
tmptime = localtime(&tmpGetTime);
cout << tmptime->tm_mday << "/" <<tmptime->tm_mon+1 << "/" << 1900+tmptime->tm_year << " " << tmptime->tm_hour << ":" << tmptime->tm_min << ":" << tmptime->tm_sec<<">>";
```

Is there any way to add milliseconds to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current timestamp in milliseconds since 1970 just the way Java gets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555121/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-milliseconds-since-1970-just-the-way-java-gets)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To have millisecond precision you have to use system calls specific to your OS.

In Linux you can use

```
#include <sys/time.h>

timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
// then convert struct tv to your needed ms precision
```

`timeval` has microsecond precision.

In Windows you can use:

```
#include <Windows.h>

SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
// then convert st to your precision needs
```

Of course you can use [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_C%2B%2B_Libraries) to do that for you :)

Comment: For Linux, you *should* read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), and probably use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)

Comment: Perhaps you could provide headers for the functions?

Answer (score 17):

//***C++11 Style:***

```
cout << "Time in Milliseconds =" << 
 chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() 
 << std::endl;

cout << "Time in MicroSeconds=" << 
 chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count() 
 << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a timer with a higher resolution in order to capture milliseconds.  Try this:

```
int cloc = clock();
//do something that takes a few milliseconds
cout << (clock() - cloc) << endl;
```

This is of course dependent on your OS.

Comment: Hum I think that clock() returns a clock_t which represent a clock unit. Moreover on linux it does not achieve a ms precision AFAIK

Comment: @neuro in my Linux program I receive double values for clock()

Answer (score 2):

The high resolution timers are usually gettimeofday on Linux style platforms and QueryPerformanceCounter on Windows.

You should be aware that timing the duration of a single operation (even with a high resolution timer) will not yield accurate results.  There are too many random factors at play.  To get reliable timing information, you should run the task to be timed in a loop and compute the average task time.  For this type of timing, the clock() function should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use any OS-specific code, you can use the ACE package which supplies the `ACE_OS::gettimeofday` function for most standard operating systems.
For example:

```
ACE_Time_Value startTime = ACE_OS::gettimeofday();

do_something();

ACE_Time_Value endTime = ACE_OS::gettimeofday();

cout << "Elapsed time: " << (endTime.sec() - startTime.sec()) << " seconds and " << double(endTime.usec() - startTime.usec()) / 1000 << " milliseconds." << endl;
```

This code will work regardless of your OS (as long as ACE supports this OS).

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 this worked for me...

```
const std::string currentDateTime() {
   char            fmt[64], buf[64];
   struct timeval  tv;
   struct tm       *tm;

   gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
   tm = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
   strftime(fmt, sizeof fmt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%%06u", tm);
   snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, fmt, tv.tv_usec);
   return buf;
}
```

Then, with...

```
std::cout << currentDateTime();
```

I get...

```
2016-12-29 11:09:55.331008
```

Answer (score 1):

New answer for old question using C++11 or C++14 and this [free, open-source library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date):

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = make_zoned(current_zone(), floor<milliseconds>(system_clock::now()));
    cout << format("%e/%m/%Y %T", now) << '\n';
}
```

This just output for me:

```
16/01/2017 15:34:32.167
```

which is my current local date and time to millisecond precision.  By eliminating the `floor<milliseconds>()` you will automatically get whatever precision your `system_clock` has.

If you wanted the result as a UTC timestamp instead of a local timestamp, it is even easier:

```
    auto now = floor<milliseconds>(system_clock::now());
    cout << format("%e/%m/%Y %T", now) << '\n';
```

And if you want a UTC timestamp and you aren't picky about the precision or the format, you can just:

```
cout << system_clock::now() << '\n';
```

which just output for me:

```
2017-01-16 20:42:11.267245
```