# How to get system time with NASM assembly in Linux without using functions exported from C?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64

I am working on a project for my university. The task is to print current date and time.
I success fully managed to create a subroutine that prints numbers, all I need now is to get date.
I tried [this approach:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465927/how-can-i-access-system-time-using-nasm)

```
%define RTCaddress  0x70
%define RTCdata     0x71

;Get time and date from RTC
.l1:    mov al,10           ;Get RTC register A
        out RTCaddress,al
        in al,RTCdata
        test al,0x80            ;Is update in progress?
        jne .l1             ; yes, wait

        mov al,0            ;Get seconds (00 to 59)
        out RTCaddress,al
        in al,RTCdata
        mov [RTCtimeSecond],al
```

But just calling:

```
.l1:    mov al,10           ;Get RTC register A
        out RTCaddress,al
```

Is enought to get a crash. Do you have any idea how to fix this approach or is there any different I could use.
I am working with Nasm on Linux 64bit.

Comment: Use @jpowel's answer in the linked question to invoke a system call. You normally won't be able to access RTC hardware from user mode unless you run as root and ask for IO privilege (which is also a system call, so ...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access system time using NASM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465927/how-can-i-access-system-time-using-nasm)

Comment: @Jester Thanks for your answer. 
The problem is that I need a full date (day/month/year) + (HH:MM:SS)
and as far as I understand sys_time call returns just seconds from some point in time.

Comment: It's your job to convert it into day/month/year. The _"some point in time"_ is 1970-01-01. The rest is just arithmetic.

Comment: @Jester Not the best way to spend time, but at least I know how to do it now :) Thanks

Comment: With system call or without? With system call, first do it with the glibc wrapper, then decompile it.

Comment: Make a call to `sys_time` directly. One good chart for 64bit syscalls is [here](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) . In this case _rax_ = 201 (decimal), _%rdi_ pointer to structure to return time and then a `syscall`

Comment: @jester : That jpowel code will work on 64-bit, but with extra overhead. The preferred way is a syscall on 64-bit Linux. The latter point why I wouldn't consider the older question/answer the same as this question (although that answer will work)

Comment: @MichaelPetch the point was, make a system call and convert the result by hand. I wasn't trying to show how to make a system call (which is a different matter) although I might have missed that this question says 64 bit so indeed it's not directly applicable.

Comment: I thought that you had a good comment @jester, was only pointing out the 64-bit aspect. The 32-bit code will work in a 64-bit app (int 0x80 works for compatibility). So I wasn't complaining about that particular point at all.

Answer (score 5):

As Jester pointed out Jpowel [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465927/how-can-i-access-system-time-using-nasm) a *similar* [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6636376/3857942). JPowel provided an answer that works for 32-bit and 64-bit. The compatibility (on 64-bit Linux) of calling through `int 0x80` has a small amount of additional overhead associated with it. The 64-bit specific method is to use the 64-bit instruction `SYSCALL` to the `sys_time` kernel routine. Linux `sys_time` manpage is [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html). It defines `sys_time` as:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   #include <time.h>
>
>   time_t time(time_t *t);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>   time() returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch,
>   1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).
>
>   If t is non-NULL, the return value is also stored in the memory
>   pointed to by t.
> ```

A good resource for the 64-bit Linux `syscall`can be found on [Ryan Chapmans blog](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64). This information can be useful for setting up the `sys_time` call using 64-Bit System V ABI kernel calling convention. His table has:

> ```
> %rax  System call    %rdi
> ---------------------------------
> 201   sys_time       time_t *tloc
> ```

This code provides an example of calling `sys_time` with a pointer to a `time_t` type (long long) and shows the second method of passing 0 as the first parameter which simply returns the time in `rax`.

```
        section .data
time:   dq      0

        global  _start
        section .text

_start:
        ; Method 1: pass a pointer to a time_t (long long) to return time in
        ; sys_time = syscall(201, *long long)

        mov     rax, 201         ; system call 0xC9(201) = sys_time
        mov     rdi, time        ; address of long long (qword) to return
                                 ;     a time_t val
        syscall                  ; make Linux system call

        ; Method 2: pass zero as the time_t parameter. sys_time returns
        ; value in rax .
        ; sys_time = syscall(201, *long long = 0)

        mov     rax, 201         ; system call 0xC9(201) = sys_time
        xor     rdi, rdi         ; address of long long (qword) set to zero
        syscall                  ; make Linux system call

        ; Do something useful with time
        ; Seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)

        ; Exit with the time
        mov     rdi, rax         ; return least sig byte of time as return code
        mov     rax, 60          ; system call 0x3C(60) is exit
        syscall                  ; make Linux system call
```

This [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1692210/3857942) suggests a reasonable implementation in C based on the source code for a C library `gmtime`function. It wouldn't be difficult to convert it to X86_64 assembler. The code is pretty straight forward. With such a function breaking up the time into individual components for formatting wouldn't be difficult at all.