# How to get current timestamp in milliseconds since 1970 just the way Java gets

Tags: c++, timestamp

In Java, we can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the current timestamp in Milliseconds since epoch time which is -

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and
>   midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

In C++ how to get the same thing?

Currently I am using this to get the current timestamp -

```
struct timeval tp;
gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
long int ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000; //get current timestamp in milliseconds

cout << ms << endl;
```

This looks right or not?

Answer (score 353, accepted):

If you have access to the C++ 11 libraries, check out the [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) library. You can use it to get the milliseconds since the Unix Epoch like this:

```
#include <chrono>

// ...

using namespace std::chrono;
milliseconds ms = duration_cast< milliseconds >(
    system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
);
```

Comment: Nice. Add count() at the end of the line to get number of milliseconds in a fundamental type format.

Comment: Will this be same if we use `steady_clock` instead of `system_clock`? Will both the epoch be same?

Comment: @lining: Both epochs are likely to be the same, but their values could be different. `steady_clock` will always progress forward, it is a true measure of the time since its epoch while `system_clock` may be a representation of the logical time since the epoch. For every leap second the two could grow further apart depending on the system's implementation.

Comment: Ok, do you know what is the epoch for `steady_clock` as compared to `system_clock`? To me epoch for the `system_clock` (on g++/linux) is in fact the system epoch, but for steady_clock it's something else I guess . And also let's say if we use `system_clock`, is there any disadvantage in leap year?

Comment: As far as I know, the epoch for each of the clocks is implementation dependent. Convention is for `system_clock`'s to be the same as the UNIX epoch, but the spec only says it must be the system-wide real time wall clock. There is no requirement for the `steady_clock` to match reality, only that it only move forward.

Comment: What's the advantage of using the c++11 chrono library as opposed to the gettimeofday?

Comment: @Jason Besides gettimeofday not being available on Windows, the chrono library can give you higher resolution (gtod is limited to microseconds), provides time units in a type-safe way so the compiler can enforce unit conversions, and works with normal arithmetic operators (adding `timeval` structs is annoying).

Comment: @P1r4nh4 I needed it in `int` but when I use `.count` it gives me a negative number.

Comment: How do I convert this to int64_t?

Comment: @Pototo as P1r4nh4 stated, call `.count()`. Check out the linked documentation for more information. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

Comment: Javascript developers are laughing at me seeing this :(

Comment: @Noitidart ,`long int ns = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();` appears to return the result in nanoseconds. To get it as an int, I'm doing `int ms = ns / 1000000 - 1550000;`, which messes with the offsets, but I'm just measuring time deltas in my project.

Comment: How can I convert this epoch ms to a datetime format where I can extract the date and time like 07/27/2020 and 20:37:46.239522 respectively?

Comment: @Potion See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58610754/321937

Answer (score 57):

Since C++11 you can use `std::chrono`:

- get current system time: `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`
- get time since epoch: `.time_since_epoch()`
- translate the underlying unit to milliseconds: `duration_cast<milliseconds>(d)`
- translate `std::chrono::milliseconds` to integer (`uint64_t` to avoid overflow)

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

uint64_t timeSinceEpochMillisec() {
  using namespace std::chrono;
  return duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << timeSinceEpochMillisec() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use `unsigned long long` instead of `uint64_t`.

Comment: Why `unsigned long long` instead of `uint64_t`? I have a natural preference for the shorter type to type

Comment: uint64_t is also more typesafe. unsigned long long might vary between systems.

Answer (score 49):

use `<sys/time.h>`

```
struct timeval tp;
gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
long int ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952290/how-can-i-get-utctime-in-milisecond-since-january-1-1970-in-c-language).

Comment: good solution, also I think it should be gettimeofday(&tp,NULL);

Comment: First of all, this is C, not C++. Secondly, there are problems with gettimeofday, see [this](https://blog.habets.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time) for example.

Answer (score 32):

This answer is pretty similar to [Oz.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19555298/3543437), using `<chrono>` for C++ -- I didn't grab it from Oz. though...

I picked up the original snippet at the [bottom of this page](http://www.epochconverter.com/), and slightly modified it to be a complete console app. I love using this lil' ol' thing. It's fantastic if you do a lot of scripting and need a reliable tool in Windows to get the epoch in actual milliseconds without resorting to using VB, or some less modern, less reader-friendly code.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned __int64 now = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    std::cout << now << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get a negative number `-560549313` this is not right, right?

Comment: @Noitidart Can you tell me what platform and C++ compiler you're using? I use this thing all the time with automation tools, and have never seen a negative output o.0 More than happy to check it though. Also, is that a direct copy, or modified/integrated program? Just want to make sure it's originating from this code only.

Comment: Ah @kayleeFrye_onDeck its because I was using `int`! `int nowms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();`. I swithced that to `int64_t` and it works! Thanks so much for asking for more info to help!

Comment: `unsigned long long` is more portable, and `__int64` is only available on MSVC.

Comment: there is no `__int64` type in standard C++. One can use `std::int64_t` instead.

Answer (score 14):

If using gettimeofday you have to cast to `long long` otherwise you will get overflows and thus not the number of milliseconds since the epoch:

```
long int msint = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;
```

will give you a number like 767990892 which is about 8 days after the epoch ;-).

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct timeval tp;
    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
    long long mslong = (long long) tp.tv_sec * 1000L + tp.tv_usec / 1000; //get current timestamp in milliseconds
    std::cout << mslong << std::endl;
}
```