# What is the difference between C++ and Java timestamps?

Tags: java, c++, timestamp

In a project using JSON as an exchange, we encountered the problem that timestamps in milliseconds in C++ and Java are completely different even though both are described as a `long` primitive data type.

What kind of standards does each language use and why is there a difference?

As an example, `1407315600` is a C++ timestamp which refers to `06.08.2014 09:00:00 UTC` while in Java it's unreadable!

Reading timestamps in Java is done using `new Date(1407315600)`.

Comment: It depends how do you use this long in Java. Usually timestamps are in milliseconds. Add your Java code if you want more help...

Comment: Can you please show us how you read this timestamp with Java?

Comment: Reading the date timestamp is usually done using `new Date(long)`. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: How was the C++ timestamp obtained?

Comment: Try `new Date(1407315600 * 1000)`. The java date requires milliseconds, the C++ timestamp you have looks like it is in seconds.

Comment: In c++ time in **seconds** since 1970, in java time in **milliseconds** since 1970

Comment: @Niall please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
new Date(1407315600 * 1000)
```

The Java date requires milliseconds, the C++ timestamp you have looks like it is in seconds.

In general, the C++ [time_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t) functions give the time in seconds since the epoch.

To get the time in milliseconds in C++ (compared to Java), please refer to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555121/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-milliseconds-since-1970-just-the-way-java-gets)

**C++11**

If C++11 is available on the platform, the [`chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) could be used to obtain a higher resolution (note; the clock may be an alias for one of the other clocks or an implementation defined clock).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    milliseconds ms;
    ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
    cout << ms.count() << endl;
}
```