# How does java generate time value in config key?

Tags: java

In path C:\Users\user\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties has a key: deployment.modified.timestamp=1491897442388

My question is how java gen "1491897442388" value of "deployment.modified.timestamp" key? It changed every time I access to Java Control Panel

Comment: This is just the current [epoch timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

Comment: why in java, timestamp has 13 charecters and in your link, it has just 10?

Comment: Ok, I knew, in miliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks very much like milliseconds since the Epoch, where the Epoch is defined as January 1, 1970 at midnight at the beginning of the day UTC (note the time zone). Your 1491897442388 corresponds to 2017-04-11T07:57:22.388Z (still UTC).

You may get such a timestamp from for example [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) or `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`.

Comment: Is there any way I get this in c++, I mean in milliseconds

Comment: Ok, tks, I found it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555121/how-to-get-current-timestamp-in-milliseconds-since-1970-just-the-way-java-gets