# Convert Milliseconds to Duration with the given format

Tags: c++, c++14, duration, c++-chrono

For a given duration of `203443` *milliseconds* (this is `3` minutes, `23` seconds and `443` milliseconds), a pattern like e.g.

```
This took about' m 'minutes and' s 'seconds.
```

would produce the following
formatted output:

```
This took about 3 minutes and 23 seconds.
```

It is different from format timestamp to current date-time. Is there any C++ standard Library (under C++14) or a solution that I can follow. I'm new to C++.

Comment: Do you have a timestamp or a duration? They are different things (different classes in the standard library). And what *do* you have? Please try to create a [mcve] to show what you have and what you're trying to do, and tell us what problems you have with that example. And perhaps take some to read or refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I think that I have a duration.

Comment: I didn't come up with any solution so that I made a question here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert milliseconds to hours:minutes:seconds:milliseconds in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727304/convert-milliseconds-to-hoursminutessecondsmilliseconds-in-c)

Comment: @sephiroth yes, but my milliseconds need to convert to years:months:days:hours:minutes:seconds: milliseconds. I have already read that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto d = 203443ms;
    auto m = duration_cast<minutes>(d);
    d -= m;
    auto s = duration_cast<seconds>(d);
    std::cout << "This took about " << m.count() << " minutes and "
                                    << s.count() << " seconds.\n";
}
```

Comment: Can I convert milliseconds to years:months:days:hours:minutes:seconds: milliseconds? Using what you just showed me??

Comment: You seem like a master about the date-time format library in C++.

Comment: Yes.  However the duration type aliases `years`, `months`,  and `days` don't exist in C++14.  But you can create such duration as is done here:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h *However*, `years` and `months` duration types would be _average_ years and months in length.  So the "about" in your message would be apropos.

Comment: I have visited your GitHub a thousand times, but I'm not allowed to use open source just only standard library. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can just write your own `years`, `months` and `days` type aliases using mine as a guide.  I can't claim a copyright on a typedef.

Comment: Yes, that what I'm doing right now. Actually my problem is with day month and year, the other types already solved.