# Creating a timestamp in c using the time_t function in c

Tags: c, windows, time, timer

I have problems to finding any examples of creating a basic time_t function to count the seconds and milliseconds, both from a zero value. Does anyone has a basic example ?.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "count the seconds" ? Can you show us how the prototype would look or how it would be called ?

Comment: Note that `time_t` is a type, not a function.  There is a function [`time()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html)
 that returns a `time_t` value.  You might need to look up [`localtime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html), [`gmtime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gmtime.html) and [`strtime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtime.html). Alternatively, you might need to look up [`clock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html).

Comment: Note that you've not specified you platform.  On most Unix-like environments, there are other high-resolution timers too. Theoretically, using [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) is best, but it is not portable to Mac OS X, whereas
[`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html), although formally marked obsolescent, is available on essentially all Unix variants.  Windows has its own, different set of APIs; I'm not familiar with the details.

Comment: I'm using Windows. What I mean is starting from a zero value, and then counting both the seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: Try 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120478/capturing-a-time-in-milliseconds or 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444428/time-stamp-in-the-c-programming-language